# Warnings on equality operators

Tags: perl, operators, warnings

Has something changed in Perl or has it always been this way, that examples like the second (`$number eq 'a'`) don't throw a warning?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;

my $string = 'l';
if ($string == 0) {};

my $number = 1;
if ($number eq 'a') {};


# Argument "l" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./perl.pl line 6.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl will be try to convert a scalar to the type required by the context where it is used.

There is a valid conversion from any scalar type to a string, so this is always done silently.

Conversion to a number is also done silently if the string passes a `looks_like_number` test (accessible through [`Scalar::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/PerlIO::eol)). Otherwise a warning is raised and a 'best guess' approximation is done anyway.

```
my $string = '9';
if ( $string == 9 ) { print "YES" };
```

Converts the string silently to integer 9, the test succeeds and `YES` is printed.

```
my $string = '9,8';
if ( $string == 9 ) { print "YES" };
```

Raises the warning `Argument "9,8" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)`, converts the string to integer 9, the test succeeds and `YES` is printed.

To my knowledge it has always been this way, at least since v5.0.

Answer (score 4):

It has been that way.

In the first `if`, `l` is considered to be in *numeric* context. However, `l` cannot be converted to a number. Therefore, a warning is emitted.

In the second `if`, the number `1` is considered to be in *string* context. Therefore the number `1` is converted to the string `'1'` before comparison and hence no warnings are emitted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a lowercase "L" on purpose? It's often hard to tell the difference between a lowercase "L" and one. You would have answered your own question if you had used a one instead.

```
>perl -wE"say '1' == 0;"


>perl -wE"say 1 eq 'a';"


>
```

As you can see,

- If one needs a number, Perl will convert a string to a number *without warning*.
- If one needs a string, Perl will convert a number to a string *without warning*.

Very consistent.

You get a warning when you try to convert a lowercase L to a number, but how is that surprising?